# Location services in mobile Safari: Don't Allow is saved...forever? Even with reset

Tags: ios, geolocation, mobile-safari

My web app using location services worked fine until I started testing "Do not allow" use cases.  Now an iPhone refuses to ever allow location services, even when I answer "OK" to "Safari" would like to use your current location.

To reproduce...
Using iPhone on iOS 5.1:

1. Load web page that makes location services calls (like http://smithsrus.com/geo.html)
2. Answer "Do not allow" when user permission prompt appears.
3. Reload page and answer "Do not allow" 2 more times.
4. Reload page and see "User Denied" without getting a prompt.
5. Go to "Settings->General->Reset->Reset Location Warnings" and tap "Reset Warnings".
6. Return to Safari, reload page and now see the user permission prompt.
7. Even if you answer "OK" the web page will still be Denied.

I kill and restart Safari, I delete all website data, I turn Location Services on and off, I even reboot, and still Safari refuses to actually Allow location services even when I say I want to.

Once you go through these steps, that web domain is dead to location services.
I'm running out of domains to test

I've searched many StackOverflow, Apple Developer and other sites for answers.
But it sure looks like a bug to me.  Answering a prompt with "Allow" but getting denied must be a bug.  After answering "Allow" the location services icon appears at the top of the screen briefly but then disappears, and in Location Services settings Safari appears with "On" and the gray icon next to it.

After trying a combination of reseting location warnings, turning on and off location services and closing and restarting the browser, I did manage to get one new error:
"The operation couldn't be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)"  Sounds buggy.

I'd rather it be something silly I am doing, can anyone tell me?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a workaround to this (beyond installing the iOS6 beta)? I just did the same thing testing a mobile web app a co-worker and I are working on and ran into the same brick wall.

Answer (score 60):

I got it after about giving up and thinking there wasn't a solution. I managed to share my location on my iPhone 4s by doing the following:

Go to **Settings -> General**, scroll to the bottom and go to **Reset-> Reset Location & Privacy**.

The next time I opened my web-app to test its user location features, it worked like a charm. Hope this helps for all who have this problem.

Comment: It's called `Reset -> Reset Location Warnings` on my iPhone 4GS with iOS 5. Worked a charm, thanks.

Comment: For the iPhone 5S on iOS 7, go to `Settings -> Privacy` then turn on Location Services.

Answer (score 8):

The following steps solved it for me:

1. Close all tabs in safari with the domain in question open.
2. Close Safari (Hold home button and cross off).
3. Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset Location Warnings / Reset Location & Privacy.
4. Open Safari and try again.

The trick (compared to mark's answer) is to make sure you close Safari fully. When I followed mark's answer, I got the prompt re-appearing for Safari itself, but not for my domain. After closing Safari then following mark's answer, I got 2 successive prompts, firstly for Safari, and then for my domain.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue caused by repeatedly hitting the "Do not allow" option.

The way I fixed this in my iPad 2 was to go into "Settings > General > Restrictions", then enable restrictions (have to enter passcode). From there I went into "Location" under the "Allow Changes" section and checked "Allow Changes" and made sure location services were on for all the listed apps. This seems to have reset it for me. After that I could go back into "General > Restriction" and disable restrictions again.

Hope this helps you!